# change menu class with jquery cokiee?

Tags: jquery

i made my css multilevel menu with a couple different class.
I want use, some cookie or etc (i couldn't do anything with jquery cokiee plugin , for my visitors.

Here is the example with my whole menu codes and color code.

http://codepen.io/fatihtoprak/pen/oqmrb

When user select / change menu background , if he refreshed the page i want to store menu class / color ?

Could any one help me about this. 
Sorry about my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`jquery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin to help you out with this. The syntax is also simple.

First step, you set a cookie, if not set, to the default menu.

```
if (!$.cookie('menu_color'))
    $.cookie('menu_color', 'blue');
```

Now you need to fetch the colour from the cookie.

```
var style = $.cookie('menu_color');
$("#modafesto").removeAttr("class").addClass("navigation").addClass(style);
```

Next thing to do is, while setting the color, update the cookie this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var style = $(this).attr("class");
        $.cookie('menu_color', style);
        $("#modafesto").removeAttr("class").addClass("navigation").addClass(style);
    });
});
```

Comment: Omg. Is this so simple like this ? :S @Kumar Thank you so much your fast and useful answer. 

Also whats your guess ? Should i set experion time for this cokiee o r not ?

I'm gonna add your name into the Special Thanks section on my .js file (:

Comment: No need of expiration. Thanks, I am glad that this worked out for you. I have created a fiddle, check that out. :) Thanks once again. BTW, do you have a github page? Are you making any plugins?

Comment: Yeap, it worked for me . Also thank you ypur fiddle too. I usually develop Wordpress Themes, Plugin etc. Here is my github page https://github.com/fatihtoprak . I m so new about jquery (:

Comment: Dude, I am following you in Twitter and sent a tweet too! :)

Comment: @Kumar if i want to add some style src file on head how could it be ? For ex. When user changed his menu class (i.e light-blue) i want to add css src file on `</head>` tag : site.com/assets/css/user_selected_style_name.css ?

Comment: You can use the same way. Have an `ID` for the `<link>` and change it using `$("#stylesheet").attr("href", "style2.css");`. As simple as that. And yeah, call me Praveen! :)

Comment: Thanks for this too. Praveen but something is funny. When i browse my categories (sef link) like ; site.com/category/sub-cat/ i can set different menu color (: I think we should -actually you- :) should add some  hack into jscript (:

Comment: @FatihToprak Will think about it. :)